# How to create a plus symbol bar button item

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

How do you create `UIBarButtonItem` as a plus symbol? I tried giving it the title "+", but I would like it to look more like the plus symbol you would normally create if you used storyboard. Which doesn't have a background or an underline.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's one of the provided bar button system items.

```
let addBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: YOUR_TARGET, action: YOUR_SELECTOR)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for:

[image: screenshot of attribute inspector in Xcode highlighting "System Item" under "Bar Button Item"]

Comment: What, exactly, do you have selected in order to bring up these options? I'm clicking all over the place on the ViewController on my `Main.storyboard`, and "Bar Button Item" is never showing up in my Attributes Inspector.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2 Example**

Here is how you do it:

```
let addBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addUser))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addBarButton
}

@objc private func addUser() {
    // Some code, e.g.
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "CreateNewUser", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "createUser") as! CreateUserVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** There is a little problem though which many users have pointed out and took me many hours to figure out as well (for iOS 11, 12) that you must put the `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addBarButton` inside the `viewDidLoad` function otherwise the button's selector won't work. This has something to do, as per other users on StackOverflow, with tap gestures. In my code, one of my view controllers have two buttons assigned outside of `viewDidLoad` function but there is also use a function to hide the keyboard, which probably causes the buttons to work fine. However, in view controllers of two other projects where I don't show or hide keyboard, the `#selector` for programatically set navigation bar buttons don't work unless they are defined within `viewDidLoad` function as in the example above. I hope this tip will save you tons of time in case you face this problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.0**

```
let addBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.openSearch))
```